# Two player number battling simulator favours second player

Tags: javascript, simulation, montecarlo

I am writing a fairly basic (for now) number crunching battle simulator in javascript. Its purpose is to test formula for a forthcoming game, so we can balance players stats.

Currently, the sim reduces a players health based on the following formula

```
player1.hp -= (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1) * player2[Math.floor(Math.random() * player2.length)].str;
```

HP starts on 100, and str is 2.

```
player2[Math.floor(Math.random() * player2.length)].str
```

The above code picks 1 of 3 "parts" of the player (head, body, legs) as each piece has its own stats.

So for any particular turn, starting with player 1, their head's HP is reduced by an amount based on the first formula (random part of player 2 picked, it's str stat is multiplied by a random number between 1 and 5)

Then player 2's parts are attacked, with a random part of player 1 being picked for the str stat.

(Yes, player 2 attacks first always currently, then player 1 - this may be the issue?)

When I run a single "battle", the results are fairly mixed. But when I run 100 or 1000 battles, player 2 typically comes out on top, with an average 60% win rate.

JS file [here](https://gist.github.com/paulcanning/11fb21ff819e6f8bbda4f5cabefde9a4) (download and run via Node)

Comment: If player 1 attacks first, does it come out on top 60% of the times? Whoever attacks first must probably be having some kind of advantage, which probably reflects reality. Maybe you can random who starts, thus evening who has the upper hand when the combat starts.

Comment: Sorry, in my code, player 2 actually attacks first, by depleting player 1's health (first the head, then the body and lastly the legs). Yes, I aim to randomise the order :) Oddly, running the simulation once (rounds = 1), lots of times, gives a roughly 50/50 split. Running it a lot of times, a few times (rounds = 1000) shows the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Player who starts always has advantage because he is 1st to be able to do the finishing blow if you think of a situation where each player has 100 hp and 1 hit = 10 damage then player who started will do the 10th hit and finish the battle while player 2 will have done only 9 hits. Randomizing damage still gives advantage as 1st player has 1 hit advantage

Comment: That is my current conclusion. I'm going to add in the randomisation of order now and see. But see my comment above about having 1 battle vs a thousand. Odd results!

Comment: So I just switch the order, so now player 1 is attacking player 2 first, and I get the same result, player 2 wins more :/ but again only in a large sample set. Running one sample several times is roughly 50/50... So confused!

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known problem in military combat simulation models which are turn-based.  There are a couple of solutions that are commonly used.  One is to randomize who gets to go first.  The second is to calculate the deltas for *both* players before applying those deltas.  The second approach has the interesting (and realistic) result that in some cases both players can be killed.